# how to access wcf service outside the host machine

Tags: wcf

I have developed a WCF service in visual studios on a machine which is on a domain network. I hosted it in IIS by first publishing to a folder. Then I created a new site on IIS, so I set the physical path to that folder that contains the published files. I browsed the new site and am able to access the service page.that is on the host machine. However, when I try accessing this on other computers within that network using the same address, it didn't open.  I am able to access it only on the host machine. Please how can I make it accessible to other computers in the network and also generally on the internet. Am using impersonation set to true, with a specified username and password. I set the credentials on IIS to the same username and password...thanks... Expecting your solutions..

Comment: Temporary turn off firewall and anti virus then check it.

Comment: Maybe you should create a rule to open the port on IIS. Check here http://wiki.mcneel.com/zoo/window7firewall

Comment: This isn't really a programming question at the moment. You may want to try ServerFault.

Comment: More information: 1. I have other websites running fine on that iis and still accessible outside the host .2.. my web config endpoint address is set to empty..3. I have impersonation set to true with username n password..please help me. Am so confused.